# How to resolve Unmet dependencies issue in Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: linux, google-chrome, ubuntu, dependencies, installation

Recently, I tried to download the Google Chrome in Ubuntu. But I couldn't installed it correctly. Now I am getting a red minus sign in upper right corner, stating that I have unmet dependencies. I tried to run the following command:

```
apt-get install -f
```

I got this output:

```
E: Could not open lock file /var/lib/dpkg/lock - -open(13: Permission denied)
E:Unable to lock the administration directory (/var/lib/dpkg/), are you root?
```

Please help. I am new to Ubuntu. so please explain what exactly I did wrong initially, and what is this all about?

Answer (score 0):

The error you are getting is common for one of two reasons:

1. You didn't run the command as root (should be `sudo apt-get install -f google-chrome`)
2. You have an updater open somewhere else (hence the lock).

I would try the command above with all other programs closed if that doesn't work see this post on the [Ubuntu SO](https://askubuntu.com/questions/510056/how-to-install-google-chrome-on-ubuntu-14-04) (which is where you should post your Ubuntu questions from now on, BTW) on how to install Google Chrome.

Good luck!